# Checking if a docker compose service is reachable from another container

Tags: python, docker

I am writing a gunicorn/uvicorn/fastapi endpoint and want it to assess if a given port on another given container (using the compose service name) is reachable (and time it). For this example this service is called mematest and the container I want to check is memaapp.

If I run a ping to memaapp from within mematest it succeeds.

If I do a "curl memaapp:4200" it succeeds.

if I run the following code from within mematest, passing it memaapp and 4200 as its parameter it returns False:

```
def check_port_with_timing(hostname, port):
    """
    Checks if a port on a given hostname is listening and measures the time taken to check.

    Parameters:
    - hostname: A string, the hostname or IP address to check.
    - port: An integer, the port number to check.

    Returns:
    - A tuple containing a boolean indicating if the port is listening and the time taken in milliseconds.
    """
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.settimeout(5)  # Increased timeout
        start_time = time.time()  # Record the start time
        try:
            result = sock.connect_ex((hostname, port))
            time_taken = (
                time.time() - start_time
            ) * 1000  # Convert time taken to milliseconds
            if result == 0:
                return True, time_taken
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            time_taken = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
            return False, time_taken

    # If connection fails for a reason other than an exception caught above
    return False, (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
```

I guess I could rewrite this function using the requests library for HTTP REST APIs but am trying to keep things at a lower communication stack level.

Comment: You might want to print the errno from `connect_ex()`.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. will do. Currently have tried replacing socket and doing a simple request but also that fails and I losing my last hair ;) since from within the same container doing a curl mema-app:4200 succeeds !!! :( :(